# SQL inner-join query

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm trying to make a inner-join, but I can get it to work.
This is my sql query

```
SELECT highscore.score, bruger.brugerNavn FROM highscore INNER JOIN bruger ON highscore.brugerID ON bruger.brugerID ORDER BY score DESC
```

I end up with this error

```
SELECT highscore.score, bruger.brugerNavn FROM highscore INNER JOIN bruger ON highscore.brugerID ON bruger.brugerID LIMIT 0, 25
#1064 - There is an error in the SQL syntax near 'ON bruger.brugerID LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

I would appreciate any help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this first:

```
SELECT h.score, b.brugerNavn 
FROM highscore as h
JOIN bruger as b ON h.brugerID = b.brugerID
```

I usually add aliases for easier handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT highscore.score, bruger.brugerNavn 
FROM highscore 
INNER JOIN bruger ON highscore.brugerID = bruger.brugerID 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You also try like that

```
SELECT highscore.score, bruger.brugerNavn 
FROM Highscore as highscore
INNER JOIN Bruger as burger ON highscore.brugerID = bruger.brugerID 
ORDER BY highscore.score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `HS.brugerID on BG.brugerID`  with `HS.brugerID = BG.brugerID` under inner join

```
SELECT HS.score, BG.brugerNavn 
FROM highscore as HS
INNER JOIN bruger as BG ON HS.brugerID = BG.brugerID 
ORDER BY highscore.score DESC
```